# CsvHelper type conversion, column with string and ints to int

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a contrived csv file

```
  "Id","Name"
  "10","Foo"
  "Team1Id","Joe"
  "Team1Id","Blogs"
  "Team2Id","Foo Bar"

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class MyClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id").???Convert???
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");
    }
}
```

I want to Map the Id column into an int, so I think I want a custom convert of "Team1Id" and "Team2Id" to some associated fixed values ("Team1Id" => -1, "Team2Id" => -2)

Comment: According to the docs you can roll your own TypeConverter , example here: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion/

Comment: Is the relationship that you want to strip the non nUmbers and make the result negative, so Team278Id would be -278?

Comment: @CaiusJard I was thinking that if there were 100,000 keys in the dictionary you'd have to read them all to determine the next value. But there would be ways around that, so I deleted the comment.

Comment: @stuartd Ah, makes sense.. yes I think I'd e.g. keep a paired number `nextId` and if I was making a new dictionary entry i'd `d[somelkey] = nextId--;` so i didnt have to Min() the dict values

Comment: Thanks @david, worked a treat.  lidqy The TypeConverter example overrides ConvertFromString / ConvertToString, I don't see how that would help.  stuart / caius I only have a few text items in the column and they don't actually contain numbers, but neat solution. thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you are looking for?

```cs
void Main()
{
    var mappings = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Team1Id", -1 }, {"Team2Id", -2 }};
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n10,Foo\nTeam1Id,Joe\nTeam1Id,Blogs\nTeam2Id,Foo Bar"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyClassMap(mappings));
        var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
    }   
}

public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap(IDictionary<string,int> mappings)
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Convert(args =>
        {
            var idValue = args.Row.GetField("Id");
            
            if (mappings.ContainsKey(idValue))
            {
                return mappings[idValue];
            } else
            {
                int.TryParse(idValue, out int value);
                
                return value;
            }
            
        });
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of D.Specht answer to incorporate stuartd's comment

```
void Main()
{
    using var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n10,Foo\nTeam1Id,Joe\nTeam1Id,Blogs\nTeam2Id,Foo Bar");
    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyClassMap(mappings));
    var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
}

public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    private _mappings = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    private _nextId = -1;

    public MyClassMap(IDictionary<string,int> mappings)
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Convert(args =>
        {
            var idValue = args.Row.GetField("Id");
            
            if(int.TryParse(idValue, out int value))
                return value;
           
            if (_mappings.TryGetValue(idValue, out int value))
                return value;
            else
                return (mappings[idValue] = nextId--);
            
        });
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you just want to strip the text away leaving only numbers, so team1234xyz becomes -1234 and 123abc456 becomes -123456:

```
void Main()
{
    using var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n10,Foo\nTeam1Id,Joe\nTeam1Id,Blogs\nTeam2Id,Foo Bar");
    using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap(new MyClassMap(mappings));
    var records = csv.GetRecords<MyClass>().ToList();
}

public class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap(IDictionary<string,int> mappings)
    {
        Map(x => x.Id).Convert(args =>
        {
            var idValue = args.Row.GetField("Id");
            
            if(int.TryParse(idValue, out int value))
                return value;
            else
                return -Convert.ToInt32(new string(value.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c))));
            
        });
        Map(x => x.Name);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```